# Why is the variable YourName = input("What is your name?") printing the user input question rather than the users input

Tags: python

I've created a program to display some pre-set variables followed by variables which take user input. I was under the impression that after the user inputs their name that the following print() function would simply use the input of the user rather than repeating the question alongside the variable input.

```
#Setup the required variables for Dialog1 and Dialog 2
MyName = "Shawn"
MyNumber = "seven"

#Sting varibles that will the print() function.
s = "Hello, my name is " + MyName + "."
ss = "My lucky number is " +MyNumber + "."

# Alternative method for both (s) and (ss) to be combined on one line.
## s = "Hello, my name is " + MyName + ". My lucky number is " +MyNumber + "."

#Print() function for the first dialog.
print(s)
print(ss)

#Dialog2 that includes user input
YourName = input("What is your name?")
print("Your name is " +YourName)
##YourNumber = input("What is your lucky number?")
##print("Your lucky number is " +YourNumber + ".")
```

The output in Eric IDE(Linux Mint 20.x) is:

```
What is your name?Jason
Your name is What is your name?Jason
```

What I wanted was the output from `print()` to simply be `Your name is Jason`

Comment: Code works fine in Repl.it. The problem is you're using a rookie IDE, use Visual Studio, or intelliJ IDEA (If you're a student you can get the ultimate version free). Also, variable names in python should be lowercase and snake-case

Comment: This also works just fine when run from the command line... I'm not sure how a an IDE (or any Python environment) could make that happen. Strange.

Comment: True, true, your code works. just tryed on pythontutor.com

Comment: @Mick is correct. The code that you have provided works, and I would agree with them that you should choose a different IDE.

Comment: I chose Spyder IDE which seems to work fine. I'm quite new to using Python IDEs especially on Linux(since this computer is old hardware that I use for Plex Server & learning things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well. As @Mick commented, may be something wrong with your IDE.
Here I have added few simple modifications that may be useful to you over the time.

```
MyName = "Shawn"
MyNumber = "seven"

print(f"Hello, my name is {MyName}.")
print(f"Hello, my name is {MyNumber}.")

YourName = input("What is your name?")
print(f"Your name is {YourName}")
```

I have removed your comments just to make this clear. Adding `f'string goes here'`, you can do string formatting by placing variable in it.

Comment: Thank you! string formatting will make things much easier so thank you for that. I am amazed at how friendly this community is.